# In chrome extension, how to use content script to inject a Vue page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to implement a JSON viewer chrome extension. I already have the Viewer implemented with Vue (http://treedoc.org). Now the problem is how can I can inject the Vue page with Chrome extension content script.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) is very helpful to inject normal javascript file in the extension. But this is with a known javascript file name.

I found [this post](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension-with-vue-js-56e50bd97972) and this [vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension) is helpful to use Vue for extension options page and override page, etc, as the entry point for them are HTML files. but the content script entry point is a javascript, to inject a javascript file in the content script, you need to know the exact file name. With the plugin and Webpack, the generated javascript files are appended with hash such as "*override.0e5e7d0a.js*"  which is not known upfront.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently I was developing chrome extension with vuejs and has the same requirement that need to inject whole Vue app to specific web page i.e. google.com, but sadly vue-router doesn't work.

I used [this boilerplate](https://github.com/Kocal/vue-web-extension) to get it working easily with least changes.

Once you created Vue project with this boilerplate then you need to update src/popup/popup.js to inject vue app in web page.

```
...
const div = document.createElement("div")
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);

new Vue({
   el: div,
   render: h => { return h(App); }
});
```

Add vue app as content scripts in manifest.json instead of browser_action or page_action.

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
    "js": [
        "popup/popup.js"
    ],
    "css": ["/popup/popup.css"]
}]
```

Here vue app will be injected on google.com only. If you want to inject in all web pages then remove matches from content_scripts

**P.S.**

Managed to vue router working with mode **abstract** and call `router.replace("/")` after `new Vue({ ..., router })`

Comment: This option works. But how can "popup.css" get referenced from "popup.js". In the HTML version, it's referenced as: <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">, but with content script, the base URL is the current page URL instead of popup.js, so we can't use relative path.

Comment: Do you want to inject vue app in web page or new empty tab?

Comment: FYI `popup.html` is not in use when we go through this approach. All CSS you write and imports will be placed in popup.css so you can mention `popup.css` in CSS of content scripts as I showed in answer.

Comment: Could you post the code about how did you solve the "router" issue?

Comment: @sparkle I just changed router mode to **abstract** and put `router.replace("/")` after initialising vue app in main file and that will be initial route.

Answer (score 0):

The `vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension` does not include a hash in the filename of content scripts, so no need to worry.

To add content scripts, configure the plugin's [`componentOptions.contentScripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension#contentscripts), as shown in this example (generated from `vue add browser-extension` from the root of a Vue CLI project):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  pluginOptions: {
    browserExtension: {
      componentOptions: {
        background: {
          entry: 'src/background.js'
        },
        contentScripts: {
          entries: {
            'content-script': [
              'src/content-scripts/content-script.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, what I need is to inject a Vue page into the existing content page. So content script needs to update the DOM with the content of a Vue page. The Vue page generated by Webpack includes one entry HTML page and a JS file with hash code in the name. It seems I find a way to do that with iframe. I still experiment with it, will update once I can make it work.